# How to split One Datatable into Two (matched record) (unmatched record) using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq, loops, datatable

I have one Datatable, i need to group the record into two, datatable(matched) and datatable(unmatched). for a record to be matched, there must be two rows having the same RRN and the sum of the two AMOUNT is equal to zero.

i have achieved this using the code below.

```
  if (InputCollection.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = InputCollection.Rows.Count - 1; i-- > 0;)
                {
                    var selectedRecord = InputCollection.Rows[i];
                    if (selectedRecord["RRN"].ToString() != "")
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < InputCollection.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
                        {
                            if (i != j)
                            {
                                var thisRecord = InputCollection.Rows[j];
                                var selectedRRN = selectedRecord["RRN"].ToString();
                                var thisRRN = thisRecord["RRN"].ToString();
                                if (selectedRRN.Trim() == thisRRN.Trim())
                                {
                                    if (Decimal.Parse(selectedRecord["AMOUNT"].ToString()) + Decimal.Parse(thisRecord["AMOUNT"].ToString()) == 0)
                                    {
                                        MatchedOutput.ImportRow(InputCollection.Rows[i]);
                                        MatchedOutput.ImportRow(InputCollection.Rows[j]);

                                        InputCollection.Rows.Remove(InputCollection.Rows[j]);
                                        InputCollection.Rows.Remove(InputCollection.Rows[i]);
                                        break;
                                    }

                                }
                            }


                        }

                    }
```

The problem with the code is that it is too slow. How can i rewrite the code above using LINQ Queries in c#? thanks.

Comment: What type `PRN` column has? You are constantly doing `ToString` and `Trim`. Why is the data not cleared of extra spaces before placing in table?

Comment: Judging by the `Decimal.Parse`, the `Amount` column stores the numbers. But then make this column of `typeof(decimal)`. And then you won't need parsing, the code will work much faster.

Comment: `Input Collection.Rows.Remove` slows down a lot, because it shifts all the other columns after deleting one. Get rid of the call to this method.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov 'Why is the data not cleared of extra spaces before placing in table? ' because its coming from an excel file

Answer (score 1):

This is not simple and Linq is not the correct method to accomplish.  See code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("RRN", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(decimal));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 1.0 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, -1.0 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 2.0 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, -2.0 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 3.0 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, -3.0 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 1.0 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, -1.0 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, 1.0 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, -1.0 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, 1.0 });

            var groupRRN = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new Match() { row = x, RRN = x.Field<string>("RRN"), amount = x.Field<decimal>("Amount"), matched = false }).GroupBy(x => x.RRN).ToList();

            DataTable matchedTable = dt.Clone();
            DataTable unmatchedTable = dt.Clone();

            foreach (var group in groupRRN)
            {
                for (int i = group.Count() - 1; i >= 1; i--)
                {
                    decimal amountI = group.Skip(i).First().amount;
                    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                    {
                        Match matchJ = group.Skip(j).First();
                        if (!matchJ.matched)
                        {
                            decimal amountJ = matchJ.amount;
                            if (amountI + amountJ == 0)
                            {
                                group.Skip(i).First().matched = true;
                                group.Skip(j).First().matched = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                foreach (Match match in group)
                {
                    if (match.matched == true)
                    {
                        matchedTable.Rows.Add(match.row.ItemArray);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        unmatchedTable.Rows.Add(match.row.ItemArray);
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }
    public class Match
    {
        public DataRow row { get; set; }
        public Boolean matched { get; set; }
        public string RRN { get; set; }
        public decimal amount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I feel this will be slower than what i have currently. a little Insight into the nature of data. This datatable has dynamic columns but all have RRN and AMOUNT. maximum columns could be up to 110 and the numbers of records could be up to 1milion.

Comment: Mine is faster with very large tables.  You algorithm is N^2/2.  Mine I create a Hash table (grouping RRN) which is log(N) to build the table.   Then searching for the pairs in each group is much quicker assuming each group is equal size.  So mine is log(N) + (Log(N)^2/2) + Log(N) = 2Log(N) + Log(N)^2/2.  So Log(N)^2 is smaller than N^2.